# Move Table Rows Up/Down, but can't move a second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, row

**I've created a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/markrummel/SEQbd/.**

I have three table rows, each with an UP and DOWN button. By clicking the DOWN button the row is switched with the row below it. By clicking the UP button the row is switched with the row above it.

Everything in my code works to switch the rows up and down. However, after a row is moved I can no longer move that row or the row it was switched with. I can still move rows that have not been moved/switched.

Is there some function I need to call to refresh the `table` in the `DOM` or the individual `tr`s? My assumption is that jQuery is just no longer recognizing these rows.

Example on jsFiddle:

1. Move **Item One** down,
2. See that now **Item One** and **Item Two** can't be moved up or down,
3. See that **Item 3** can still be moved up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It because you destroy the elements where you a bound the click event. You can easily fix it by deligating the event using [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

Change the first line to:

```
$(document).on("click", 'button.change-rank', function() {
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SEQbd/2/

---

But this isn't the best approach. I would make sure to move the elements around and not destroying / creating elements all the time. Instead of using `.html()` and `.html(someStrng)`, you can use `.append( [jQuery Element/DOM Node] )`

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/SEQbd/4/

---

You can write your code as simple as this: http://jsfiddle.net/3Wkfm/

```
$('button.change-rank').click(function() {                                                               
    var direction = $(this).attr('data-direction'),
        $original = $(this).closest("tr"),
        $target = direction === "up" ? $original.prev() : $original.next();

    if ( $target.length && direction === "up" ) {
        $original.insertBefore($target);
    }
    else if( $target.length ) {
        $original.insertAfter($target);
    }
});
```

`var a = condition ? c : d` is the same as writing:

```
if ( condition ) {
    var a = c;
}
else {
    var a = d;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the working demo! I'm not quite sure how to use the `.append` in this situation, because I don't simply replace each `.html()`. I don't want to append `TR` content to the new `TR` without removing the old content. Chicken and egg situation. Do I simply append to a holding `DIV` and then when ready append to the new `TR`? Does it take more to process the destroying/creating of elements and that is why `.append` is better? Is there some other reason?

Comment: @MarkRummel I have commented your lines out and put in my own right after it: See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/SEQbd/4/ . Also remember to accept the answer if it provided you the right information

Comment: Than you! I will review all of this in the morning and I'm sure will accept after I get it all working. I'm still curious as to why append is better. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `append` it better because you use the same elements all every time. It's sort of the same as saying 1+1 or 2 we both know that 1+1 equals 2 but if you will need the 2 there is no reason to every time to say 1+1 or think of the math being more complex: `(100/500*1.5^2)` witch is equal to 0.45. This is just to illustrate but it's not the same. ;).

Comment: Btw I updated your code so you don't have to use all the id's and stuff. Also to show you how simple you can make it: http://jsfiddle.net/3Wkfm/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I wish I could give you multiple up-votes for this answer! I have learned a lot and was able to cleanup other areas of my code as well with what I learned from your code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason should be event binding is lost, as you rebuild the table via .html(), what you need to do is just rebind your function to those moved buttons, or just do not move the button, I mean only move the first td or something.

Comment: That is an interesting idea to not move the buttons, but I think the fact that the table row IDs and data attributes change it might still get confused. I'm not sure. Maybe it is worth checking out. How can I rebind the buttons or rebind the TRs?

Comment: maybe set ids on td instead of tr, or even just do not move anything but just change id value on your element